# Javascript/Datatables: How to find a row in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have created a js datatable with column id, name, content.

I want to get the row object which has id=number, which I can use select method on it.

How can I do it?

I used the rows().every() method to find the row, but I think it's kind of stupid.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you what to find the column's 2 value based on the id(first column) then you should do something like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    var data = this.data();
    if(data[0]==2){ //if id == 2
        // ... do something with data(), or this.node(), etc
        alert(data[1]); 
    }
} );
```

Check out this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnd5e0ax/1/)

For more info on this you can also check [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.every%28%29)